# Locking a website to a individual system

Tags: mac, internet, ip, website

Recently i tried to visit a website to vote for a competition. After voting for first time , visiting the same page after 2 days it was not allowing to vote. It detected I already visited page. It didn't collect any details for voting.

How is this possible . Can anyone explain ?

Comment: https://thebrendans.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/delete-cookies.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution website wise would be IP detection. Try to vote trough Tor, a VPN or Proxy connection. If that works, it might be the case.

Some providers change the IP relatively seldom, even if you don't have a fixed IP. Making it possible to identify you or at least the connection for a quite long period.

Although it isn't too smart, since the worst case would be that many people can no longer participate (e.g. company internet) – it is possible.

Combining the IP with all the client information the website can easily gather (like OS, browser version, language setting, connection speed, local time, resolution) leads to very good detectability of a single client.

So try to vary one/or multiple of these informations to find out what the website really used to detect you. The website https://panopticlick.eff.org offers a test to demonstrate how trackable your browser is.

Also, as Roald van Doorn, pointed out in his comment. It could be a simple Cookie. But since this is very, very easy to bypass my experience is that these polls and competitions at least try to make a simple client detection.